# Recursion Code Failing

Tags: python, recursion

New to python - appreciate help getting function dot working and understanding what I'm doing wrong.

```
 def dot(l,k):  """multiply each elements in list l with each element from list k and return the total
    """
    total = 0


    if l == [] or '':
        return
    else:
        last_l = l[-1]
        last_2 = k[-1]
        total += last_2 * last_l
        return total + dot(l[:-1], k[:-1])

 l = [1, 2]
 k = [3, 4]

 print(dot(l,k))
```

Comment: You need to return `0` at the if statement.

Comment: As commented by Psidom you need to return 0 on the if so the last element can be added or you would have something like 2+3+None which is invalid

Comment: One other thing: the "or ''" isn't going to have any effect since it's always false.  I think you mean "or l == ""'.  Actually I'd just omit that clause, requiring the caller to pass in a list.

Comment: Thanks a million worked perfectly - now I need to learn how to vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using map and reduce on a much simpler way:

```
l1=[1,2]
l2=[2,3]

mult = lambda l1,l2: [x*y for x,y in zip(l1,l2)]

print reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,mult(l1,l2))
```